# Android tablelayout with buttons force closes - no errors in eclipse - WHY?

Tags: android

I created a new project and the only thing I changed was the activity_main.xml file. I changed the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout and set android:orientation="vertical", and then I added the following components inside this layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/b00"
        android:text="X"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b01"
        android:text="X"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b02"
        android:text="X"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:text="X"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:text="X"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:text="X"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/b20"
        android:text="X"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b21"
        android:text="X"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b22"
        android:text="X"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Upon testing this app, nothing shows up (no buttons or anything). It runs for a few seconds like this and then force closes. Please help!

EDIT: This is what logcat says...

```
03-10 18:10:02.190: I/dalvikvm(25796): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
03-10 18:10:02.200: I/dalvikvm(25796): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-10 18:10:06.720: I/Process(25796): Sending signal. PID: 25796 SIG: 9
```

I can't find /data/anr/traces.txt.

Comment: Share the logcat pleae

Comment: Read here for more information on debugging in android: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html Logcats usually save the day.

Comment: Were you planning on setting height/width for any of these components?

Comment: @Sean I edited, is this what you meant?

Comment: @Geobits Setting the height/width does not fix the problem.

Comment: Where is your `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` attributes? These are required and you have none in the layout XML posted.

Comment: @Tigger I edited. There's still an error. Are those required for all of the buttons as well?

Comment: Yes, they are required for all entities.

Comment: Okay that was the problem. I added those for all of the buttons and now it no longer force closes. Thanks

Comment: Just to clean things up (for others that may find this question), I've posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes to your layout XML entities. For example:

Change:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b00"
    android:text="X">
</Button>
```

To:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="X">
</Button>
```